# Java FTP not working inside SwingWorker Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, ftp4j

I have a simple GUI program that does some interactions with a database then once its completed ftps up some files to a server. This has worked perfectly until I added a SwingWorker thread to keep the GUI responsive.

The code I am using works fine if I put it in its standalone project but inside this project (SwingWorker thread) it gives me the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.NVTASCIIReader.readLine(NVTASCIIReader.java:105)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.read(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:142)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.readFTPReply(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:187)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.openActiveDataTransferChannel(FTPClient.java:3511)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.openDataTransferChannel(FTPClient.java:3475)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.upload(FTPClient.java:2641)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.upload(FTPClient.java:2550)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.upload(FTPClient.java:2421)
at GUI$MatchFiles.doInBackground(GUI.java:1602)
at GUI$MatchFiles.doInBackground(GUI.java:1)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I assume you mean something like this? Please note this is a very trimmed down version, I have removed a lot of superfluous code. I cant see any of it affecting this.

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer>{
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception{
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        client.connect(url);
        client.login(username, password);
        client.setPassive(false);
        client.changeDirectory(uploaddirectory);
        client.upload(new File(fileuploadpath));
        client.disconnect(true);
    }

    protected void done() {                
        System.out.println("Done");                 
    }
}
```

As said, I take this code inside the swingworker and put it in its own class and it runs perfect.

Comment: Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that illustrates the issue.

Comment: I added a code example to show what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your socket is cut-off by your firewall or anti-virus... Try disabling the firewall and anti-virus and re-run your program...